# How to run a program on a specific remote computer

Tags: batch-file, parameters, vbscript

I have got this working line of code 
I would like to run via VBScript a share program on a remote computer in a domain environment. The first part is ok where it is asking me to enter a computer name, but the problem is in the second part. I don't know how to run the program on the remote computer that I've entered in the first part.

```
computer = inputbox ("What computer do you wish to check? (Press Enter if this computer)","Computer")

set WMI = GetObject("WinMgmts://" & computer)

If computer="" then computer = "this computer"



Dim objShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

objShell.Run("""\\compname\Share\progr.exe""")

Set objShell = nothing
```

After running this script, it runs the program on my computer, not on the remote computer. I want to run the program on a specific computer that I have entered from keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

From vbscript, the better way is using wmi. Please refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a complete information on how to get a connection to a remote computer via wmi and the problems you will face to do it.

Follow the information in microsoft page, and you will end with a objWMIService variable pointing to the WMI services of the remote machine. Then,

```
    Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")

Dim strProcess
    strProcess = "notepad.exe"

Dim lngReturn, intPID
    lngReturn = objProcess.Create(strProcess, null, null, intPID)

    If lngReturn = 0 Then
        Wscript.Echo strProcess + " started. PID: " & intPID
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "Error: " & lngReturn
    End If
```

use objWMIService (remember, its the remote machine) to get a reference to the processes collection (of the remote machine), and create a new process.

Comment: Establishing the WMI connection to the remote host is one additional line. You should add this extra line to make the answer self-contained. The reference to the MSDN page is useful for getting a deeper insight, but it shouldn't be necessary for the OP to follow it to get a working solution out of the answer.

Comment: In the simplest form, you are right, one line, But i don't know if user needs to supply credentials or not, or what their requirements are. The reasons and needs of each options are better explained in MSDN, including code samples, and the OP can ask for clarifications if necessary.